# Image from database does not display on web page

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to display the image on web page from database , but it just displayed the file name of my image on web page

the code for fetching image is

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
$query = "SELECT * FROM blog_posts";
$data  = mysqli_query($link, $query);
$total = mysqli_num_rows($data);

while ($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data)) {

    echo $result['title'] . "<br>" . $result['author'] . "<br>" . $result['file_name'] . "<br>" . $result['body'] . "<br>";

}

?>
```

Comment: Because you're just printing out the image file_name. It needs to be in an [img tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img)

Comment: Might help if you wrap it in `<img>` tags?

Comment: Images must be withing `<img>` tag

Comment: or the newer `<picture>` HTML5 tag to add to the rest of the comments..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just change this line

`echo $result['title'] . "<br>" . $result['author'] . "<br> <img src '" . $result['file_name'] . "'><br>" . $result['body'] . "<br>";`

but you should get the full directory of file not just name or 
you should write it like this

`$file_name ="/dir/dir/".$result['file_name'];`

and after that you can put the $filename in img tag like this 
`echo "<img src='$file_name'>";`

Comment: $query = "SELECT * FROM blog_posts";
       $data  = mysqli_query($link, $query);
       $total = mysqli_num_rows($data);    
   
                         while ($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data)) {

                          echo $result['title']."<br>". $result['author']."<br>" .$result['body']."<br>";
                           $file_name = "uploads/".$result['file_name'];
                           echo "<img src='$file_name'>";
        }